# Multiple game projects per Play Console application? The debugging case

Tags: google-play-games

The Google Play Console enables the developer to bind a game project to an application. Only one game project can be bound to a given application.

I understand that a game project is a link between the application and a cloud project. A cloud project has, eg, Firebase messaging abilities.

Currently, my application (a game) is using Cloud Project A in production, and Cloud Project B for development, with different Firebase credentials. This is useful because I can use the same device for production and development purposes: development-mode Firebase messages won't be received by the production version of my application, and the other way around.

For Play Games Services, however, I can only have one game project, bound to one given Cloud Project. For Firebase, I can specify the development Firebase account ID in my source code (`google-services.json` and related files), but I cannot specify another game project. In the `strings.xml` file below, used by a `meta` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`, I can only specify one game project:

```
<resources>
    <string translatable="false" name="game_services_project_id">XXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
</resources>
```

Only id XXXXXXXXXXXX will work here, and that's the game project ID that is statically bound to my application in the Play Console.

Isn't there a way to specify another game project, for the same application, for development purposes?
I can't create another application because this application cannot share the same package name.

Or shall I just use the same game project for debugging (is that expected)?